# Heroku, nodejs, mongodb

Tags: node.js, heroku, mongoose

I just hosted my site on Heroku, but when I visited the site, it shows me "internal server error". But one thing I think may cause this error is I use mongoose's url as
mongoose.uri(mongodb://localhost:2725/user
So, Is it Okey to do this way? Or do I have to use cloud databases?
Or am I going use site's url which given by the Heroku instead of the localhost?

Answer (score 0):

local host address is not valid for deploying your app
you must using cloud database
mongodb gives you free database service(mongodb atlas)